# I'm displaying items as company–>all items, repeat. how to do company-->size-->items, repeat

Tags: php

I currently have the following code... it works perfectly but I need to change it:

```
$group = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $group[ $row['company'] ][] = $row;
    }
    foreach ($group as $company => $items) {
         echo "$company<br/>";
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                    $image = "item_img_url_code_goes_here";
                    echo "<img src='$image'/>";
                    $item_name = $item['item'];
                    $item_size = $item['item_size'];
                    $item_version = $item['item_version'];
                    echo "<p>$item_name - $item_size - $item_version</p>";
            }
        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
    }
```

Which outputs like this:

```
COMPANY 1
item - item size - item version
item - item size - item version
item - item size - item version

COMPANY 2
item - item size - item version
item - item size - item version
item - item size - item version
```

But I would like it to output like this:

```
COMPANY 1
item size one
item - item version
item - item version
item - item version
item size two
item - item version
item - item version
item - item version
etc

COMPANY 2
item size one
item - item version
item - item version
item - item version
item size two
item - item version
item - item version
item - item version
etc
```

Can anyone offer me any direction as to how I would achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of echoing the data immediately you can first store it in a new array with a structure like this:

```
data['sizeA']['item1'] = item1
data['sizeA']['item2'] = item2
data['sizeB']['item1'] = item3
data['sizeB']['item2'] = item4
```

Then iterate over that new array with nested loops:

```
foreach($data as $size -> $items) {
  echo "$size";
  foreach($items as $item) {
    $name = $item['name'];
    // etc.
    echo "$name";
  }
}
```